# joomla programming

Tags: php, joomla

I am a newbie in joomla programming. i am modifying an already written template which is a basic version. I want to enable commenting options for each of the item in my website and store them in my db and also display the most latest comments say recent 10 from my database on the side panel of my website.(like user activities in facebook). Are there any extensions capable of doing this?

Can anyone please guide me on this ?

Comment: is there a good extension which is doing this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [K2](http://getk2.org) which is a very extended article manager and includes a comments system.

If you don't want to use a completely separate article manager, then you can always install a component such as [JComments](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/articles-comments/9985) which integrates with standard Joomla articles.

In future, always be sure to have a look on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org) which is the directory for Joomla extensions, both commercial and non-commercial. I'm sure there will always be something that will suit your needs ;)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am just going through the extensions you have mentioned. since I am not very experienced, I may sound dumb but does these extensions handle the db storage as well?

Comment: You're more than welcome. Yes, these extensions use database storage. Whenever it comes to storing data with Joomla, a database is always used as it's more secure than the likes of an XML file ;)

Comment: as this is a related to something else, I would suggest you create a new question ;)